# Retrofit - Convert Json response to easily store data with Room

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, android-room

Is it possible to convert this  :

```
{
"news": [
 {
  "nid": 1,
  "type": "test1",
 },
 {
  "nid": 2,
  "type": "test2",
 }
]
}
```

To this when I receive the result with Retrofit ?

```
 {
  "nid": 1,
  "type": "test1",
 },
 {
  "nid": 2,
  "type": "test2",
 }
```

Actually in my model, I have a **NewsList** object with a List of **News** inside (with value inside : nid, type).
And the Retrofit query looks like this :

```
@GET("test/test.json")
suspend fun getListNews(): Response<Newslist>
```

Everything is working fine, but now I need to save that data in a database with Room and it will be easier if the Retrofit query was like this :

```
@GET("test/test.json")
suspend fun getListNews(): Response<List<News>
```

What is the best way to achieve this ?

1. Convert Json response to get something like above ?
2. Keep things like this and Convert the NewsList to be able to be stored in the Room Database ?

Comment: Why can't you just get the list of `News` using `Newslist.news` if that `Newslist` object contains a list of `News`

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use RXJava or Coroutine of Kotlin.

In RXJava you can use map operator to transform your response object to list of objects.

Please refer below link to get some idea of using RXJava with retrofit and transforming results:

https://www.journaldev.com/20433/android-rxjava-retrofit

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to have your backend server return the canonical json data.

If this is not possible, you can customize the converterFactor by addConverterFactory method，compatible with this data format in a custom converterFactor.

Comment: Yes, but I can't change the API. Do you have a useful like about the converterFactor thing please ?

Comment: You can use regular expressions in the converter factory to check if the data is in the format you want，if true then parse it, else splice string into your format, and you can modify converter according to this. 

https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-converters/gson/src/main/java/retrofit2/converter/gson/GsonResponseBodyConverter.java

Answer (score 0):

first, you must to have one layer for data provider to provide for consumer (activity, VM, fragment, etc).
in this layer, you have use case to define data collection from Cloud(Retrofit) or from Local Storage(Room). more info, i have sample [here](https://github.com/rakaadinugroho/mvvm-football)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, using data classes, you just need to create a  data class called news with a list of items with "nid" and "type", in that cases I use a plugging of Android Studio Called Kotlin data class File from JSON

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way is to return NewsList object, because it makes you easier to compatible with new feature update, like adding more fields to NewsList object. You can create a new layer for saving your data to room database, and convert the raw data to List for saving it.